# How to get HTTP error response code 403 in jQuery UI Autocomplete Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using the jQuery UI autocomplete feature for some `<input type='text'>` boxes where it should return some selections depending on the input. This is working fine but now I need to add a check if the user even is allowed to do this lookup and if not, the user should be alerted.

This is my current code (or some of it at least):

```
$(this).autocomplete({
  source: function(request,response) {

    $.ajax({
      url: 'search.json',
      data: { field: thisName,
              search: request.term }
    }).done(function(data) {
        response(data);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.dir(jqXHR);
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(errorThrown);
    });
  },
  minLength: 1,
  ...[CUT]...
```

If I inside my `search.json` only has this `http_response_code(403);` I will receive this in the console (I hope the picture is readable):

[image: Chrome JS console]

So my question is - **how can I report back an error to the autocomplete script so it acts correctly?** For example it could alert the user in some way.

Currently I want to report back with a `403 Forbidden` code but there could be other errors too - e.g. the user session could expire or alike. It doesn't necessarily needs to be a HTTP response code but this is what I see as the most correct to use in this scenario?

Please see the [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8vm7P/1/) for my code.

I am using jQuery 1.11.0 and jQuery-UI 1.10.4 together with PHP 5.4 on an IIS 7.5. The IIS will pass `.json` files as normal PHP files - just to clarify if important.

Comment: @vogomatix - that would treat it as a valid result and set it as a selection for the autocomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found out that this was caused by me having my own error pages defined in the IIS. When changing the errorcode 403 to someting else (e.g. 999) I will get the 403 error to my Ajax script:

[image: IIS selfdefined errorcodes]

[image: Chrome JS console]

I have answered this myself in case others are having a similar problem and not being aware that their selfdefined HTML error messages/pages will give a HTTP response code of 200 in the Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Using AjaxSetup seems to be an option:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    error: function (x, status, error) {
        if (x.status == 403) {
            alert("Sorry, your session has expired. Please login again to continue");
            window.location.href ="/Account/Login";
        }
        else {
            alert("An error occurred: " + status + "nError: " + error);
        }
    }
});
```

Source: http://cypressnorth.com/programming/global-ajax-error-handling-with-jquery/

Since $.ajax() also supports the error method, it might also work for $.ajax() itself.

Comment: Quote from [jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) `The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.`

Comment: ah, I'm sorry. Good to see you found the answer, have been struggling with error handling where IIS interviened as well.